# What's this board game with an old radio and some country flags on it?

Tags: identify-this-game

This is the boardgame in question. What is it?

The capital cities listed are Paris, London, Brussels, Berlin, Rome, and Vienna. There's a number of spaces that say "Tune" and it appears to have an old AM radio in the center.

[image: board game in question]

Comment: Any mention of a Copyright? That would give a year and a company name.

Comment: Any writing on the back of the board?

Comment: nothing on the back of the board sadly, and no accessories

Answer (score 1):

Must be a specific version of the Radio Broadcast Game:
https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/159448/radio-sende-spiel

While the images on boardgamegeek show slightly different boards, your board has the same features: namely exactly 100 spaces and old wartime flags for Germany and Italy. So the description fits perfectly and it must be some version of this game:

"This is a simple roll and move game with the objective of touring wartime Germany and being the first to reach the final (100) space.

However, the primary objective of the game was to encourage both patriotism and obedience to wartime rules, specifically the prohibition on listening to foreign broadcasters.

When landing on domestic transmitter spaces, the players must carry out certain actions: sing a ditty, send a message, make a weather report or sing a military song. But if they land on a foreign transmitter space, they must exclaim "I have committed a criminal offense", pay a pfennig into the pot and go back to start. Worst is if they land on London's transmitter, when they must shout "God punish England!" and pay 5 pfennig into the pot as well as start over. The pot is taken by the winner."

Not sure where you found this but the game is likely quite old (like 50s or so), I'ld like to own a copy of that if you're selling :)

Comment: If the objective of the game was to discourage Germans from listening to foreign broadcasters, the instructions on the board ("START HERE", "RETURN TO STARTING POINT"  ) and the city names would be written in German, not English.

Comment: The game displayed could not date from the 2nd World War since the German flag displayed on the board, a variant flag of the Federal Republic of Germany was adopted in June, 1950 so, 5 years after the war.
Strangely, the flag of the Kingdom of Italy on the board would be correct for wartime; it was replaced by the Republic of Italy flag, the one we now recognise, in 1946.

Comment: Yes indeed, probably created some years after WW2. Maybe the description on boardgamegeek is not entirely aligned with this board (cfr your language remark). But apart from that it all fits: the radio theme, the flags, 100 spaces and what seems to be a simple roll and move game.